# show if $U_1 \cap (U_2 + U_3) = (U_1 \cap U_2) + (U_1 \cap U_3)$ is true or false.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have no idea how to prove this, i don't even know whether it is true or not:

Suppose $U_1,U_2,U_3$ are subspaces of $V$ then $U_1 \cap (U_2 + U_3) = (U_1 \cap U_2) + (U_1 \cap U_3)$.

I tried to prove to it but i came to the solution that this not true because $U_1 + U_2$ is a sumspace and if $U_1 = (U_2+ U_3)$ then the equility will not hold.

Is this answer correct or does the equality hold? I don't need full proof but a little bit explanation will be enough.

Comment: Why won't the equality hold if $U_1 = U_2 + U_3$?

Comment: @Mark suppose if $v = U_1 + U_2$ then this vector is sum of vectors from two subspaes and intersection will not be zero in first case but in second well

Comment: The equality is called distributive law; so your question can be rephrased as 'Is the lattice of subspaces of a vector space distributive?' —The answer is no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't hold in general. Suppose we're working in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Take:\begin{align}U_1&=\bigl\{(x,x)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\bigr\}\\U_2&=\bigl\{(x,0)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\bigr\}\\U_3&=\bigl\{(0,x)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\bigr\}.\end{align}Note that

- $U_2+U_3=\mathbb{R}^2$;
- $U_1\cap U_2=U_1\cap U_3=\{0\}$.